# Doubled first keypress in Activities "Type to search" box

Tags: activities-overview, dialog

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.1 (upgraded from 20.04) on an older Acer Predator G3260 with a guest version of 22.10 installed in VirtualBox.  In the last few days something strange has stated to occur. On both the host and the guest when I click on "Activities" in the upper left corner of the Desktop the "Type to search" box opens at the top center of the Desktop as normal.  However when I start to type in the box the first keypress is doubled. Further key presses are processed as normal, as are all key presses in other dialog boxes and other apps like a terminal or a text processor window.  This doesn't happen on either a NUC8i3 or a Raspberry Pi 4B, both with 22.10 installed, so I suspect it is something to do with this particular machine and OS. The fact it only occurs in the "Type to search" dialog box suggests it doesn't have anything to do with the key repeat settings, however I have absolutely no idea where to start looking for the cause of the problem.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but i can confirm its not just you.  I upgraded from 22.04 to 22.10 using `dist-upgrade`  and have the same experience.

EDIT
just ran `apt update; apt upgrade` and it updated about 10 dbus packages.  After reboot, it seems to be fixed.  Thank goodness, it was really really irritating.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  I've run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` but it hasn't helped me.  I've done several distro upgrades over the years and it may be time for a fresh install.

Comment: it came back, but then i found https://forum.manjaro.org/t/first-character-appears-twice-in-activities-overview/125636 .

i disabled dash to dock and went back to ubuntu dock and it seems to be gone again